# Default Wordpress menu content

Tags: menus

I have several menus in my theme, but if I don't create menu in dashboard, then in those menus is displayed default menu. How can I avoid that? I don't want any menu content until I create one.

This is my code:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'main_menu_4', 'depth' => 1));?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `fallback_cb` argument of [`wp_nav_menu()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/):

> *(callable|bool)* If the menu doesn't exists, a callback function will fire. Default is 'wp_page_menu'. Set to false for no fallback.

```
<?php
wp_nav_menu( array( 
    'theme_location' => 'main_menu_4',
    'fallback_cb'    => false
    'depth'          => 1, 
) );
?>
```